# Facebook Share og:title not pulling variable on Cakephp 3

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-3.x, og-meta

I am having a bit of a problem with my Facebook sharing, and I was hoping for some input.

I'm using og meta to share my website on facebook and it work perfectly with static text. BUT when I trying with a dynamicale text using some variable it doen't work anymore for an unknown reason.

It's like if facebook get  metadata's content before variable display...

This work:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
```

This too:

```
<?php $title = 'my tilte'; ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $title; ?>" />
```

But not this:

> view.ctp

```
$this->assign('metaTitle', $post->title);
```

> default.ctp (cakephp layout)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $this->fetch('metaTitle'); ?>" />
```

I'm using Cakephp 3, `$this->fetch` is just a way to display variable from view in the layout.

In all three cases, the result is exactly the same in chrome inspector.
And I already try to debug it with [facebook tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: What is the URL you are sharing?

Comment: <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-site.com/"/>

should I write the exact post url ?
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-site.com/controller/slug"/>

Comment: No that is your og tag with a fake URL.

Comment: On the facebook debbuger, for example the og:title: it writing 

    <meta property="og:title" content="" />

But on the google inspector it's writing

    <meta property="og:title" content="Flapo - Dear Neighbor">

I try this:
`<meta property="og:title" content="te<?= $this->fetch('metaTitle') ?>st" />`
and this is the result (in the debugger):`<meta property="og:title" content="test">`


But in the browser it perfectly works !

So Facebook get the page before the variables display. Any solutions ?